# Better way to return a Future with async going on too

Tags: scala

```
def fun = {
  val a = Future {println("Inside Future"); throw new Exception("Discomfort in the sea has pulled itself upon me"); 5}
  a onComplete {_ => Thread.sleep(5000); println("Inside map") }
  a
}
```

Above is a very simple snippet. The return type is `Future`. Is there a better way without storing the value of `Future` in a `val` and still have `onComplete` but still be able to return the `Future`?

Answer (score 3):

[`andThen`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/concurrent/Future.html#andThen[U](pf:PartialFunction[scala.util.Try[T],U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) is there to help with side effects. Note that the value that is returned inside the call to `andThen` is ignored, even if an exception is thrown.

```
def fun = {
  Future {println("Inside Future"); throw new Exception("Discomfort in the sea has pulled itself upon me"); 5}
    .andThen {case _ => Thread.sleep(5000); println("Inside map") }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`onComplete` returns unit so if you specifically want to use `onComplete` you need the temporary variable. Alternatively, with Scala 2.12, you can use transform to do something similar. Note that you always need the return value:

```
  def fun = {
    Future {
      println("Inside Future")
      throw new Exception("Discomfort in the sea has pulled itself upon me")
      5
    }.transform {
      res =>
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        println("Inside map")
        res
    }
  }
```

An alternative for any Scala version is to just do both map and recover with the same body, but it wouldn't be as elegant.